# Dual Monitor Configuration changes to "Mirrored" automatically

Tags: multiple-monitors

After installing 12.04 on my Samsung X120 Notebook (with Intel GMA 4500 internal graphics card) i have a Problem with the configuration off my 2nd monitor.

Its a 22" with 1680 * 1050 Pixel connected via HDMI.

I use the display configuration and set internal display=off and external display=main display. That works fine.
After rebooting i still have that configuration, but after a while (often when i press a button on the keyboard), the configuration automatically changes to "Mirror Screen" and the internal display switches on. Both displays then have a bad resolution.
When i do the manual display configuration again, everything is fine for the duration of that session.

What could be the problem, that this display configuration gets lost / resets?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the very same problem, not just with 12.04 but with previous versions as well as mint, xubuntu and others.

I got so fed up I switched over to arch for the last 8 months or so, but when they switched over to systemd I had all sorts of problems and installed ubuntu again.

Problems started again. This time I noticed that if it was going to happen it would normally be soon after boot up. then I would reset it and it would be fine for the rest of the day.

Putting two and two together I had a look in cron.daily and ran each cron job separately. The apt job would crash X every time. There is also a `apt-xapian-index` job in cron.weekly that has the same effect.

So I just disabled the jobs (`chmod -x`) and the problems have stopped. 
Inside both of these scripts is a check to see if you are on ac power. If I run this X crashes, so I think the culprit is the `on_ac_power` command.

To see if you have the same problem open a shell and type `on_ac_power`. If you get a crash then you have the same problem as me.

Hopefully this will fix the issue for some people

Answer (score 1):

I played a bit with xrandr, the monitors.xml and so on but i couldn't solve the problem.
Now I've made a bash-script with xrandr commandscommands, that brings the recommended configuration back, and assigned it with a shortcut.
So, i think, i can live with that issue.
Thanks for your attention and greets from Austria!